# Google Translate API authentication key and usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-api, google-translate

From https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/setup-basic, there's a need to set the environmental variable:

```bash
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path/to/credential.json'
```

Then a curl request can be made as such:

```bash
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    --data "{
  'q': 'The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the
        Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in
        the Giza pyramid complex.',
  'source': 'en',
  'target': 'es',
  'format': 'text'
}" "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
```

Where there is a `Bearer` authentication key in the header of the request that comes from the value of the `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` command.

After trying several calls to `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`, every call seems to create a unique token per call.

My questions are ,

- **How long does the authentication key from `print-access-token` lasts before it expires?**
- **Is there a way to create a fix key that isn't dynamically generated from `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` and without the need to setup the environmental variable?**
- Is there a way to generate the `print-access-token` programmatically without calling the `gcloud` command line executable?

There are also seems to be a way to create a static key and use it as described in https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys and e.g. https://github.com/eddiesigner/sketch-translate-me/wiki/Generate-a-Google-API-Key

**How can the static key be used in the the curl call in place of the `Authorization: Bearer`?**

Comment: I think the tutorial might be not clear on both concepts: gcloud generated tokens and service account keys. Have you tried simply passing the credentials instead of the generated token? Changing the header: `Bearer: "$(cat /path/to/credentials.json)` (or alternatively printing the env var instead of the file).

Answer (score 16):

> How long does the authentication key from print-access-token lasts before it expires?

`print-access-token` gives you a Google access token which has a duration of 1 hour. You can check the expiration time using the [token info endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint) :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Note that the token info works both for checking `access_token` and for `id_token`

> Is there a way to create a fix key that isn't dynamically generated
>   from gcloud auth application-default print-access-token and without
>   the need to setup the environmental variable?

The credential file you have downloaded when making request to the translation API is made for [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount) aka server-to-server interactions

It's possible to re-create the flow that is used by the `gcloud` CLI using a small script that would :

- build and encode the JWT payload from the data from credentials files (to populate `aud`, `iss`, `sub`, `iat` and `exp`)
- request an access token using that JWT
- make the request to the API using this access token

The complete guide for this flow is located here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Here is an example in [python](/questions/tagged/python). You will need to install `pycrypto` and `pyjwt` to run this script :

```python
import requests
import json
import jwt
import time

#for RS256
from jwt.contrib.algorithms.pycrypto import RSAAlgorithm
jwt.register_algorithm('RS256', RSAAlgorithm(RSAAlgorithm.SHA256))

token_url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
credentials_file_path = "./google.json"

#build and sign JWT
def build_jwt(config):
    iat = int(time.time())
    exp = iat + 3600
    payload = {
        'iss': config["client_email"],
        'sub': config["client_email"],
        'aud': token_url,
        'iat': iat,
        'exp': exp,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    }
    jwt_headers = {
        'kid': config["private_key_id"],
        "alg": 'RS256',
        "typ": 'JWT'
    }
    signed_jwt = jwt.encode(
        payload, 
        config["private_key"], 
        headers = jwt_headers,
        algorithm = 'RS256'
    )
    return signed_jwt

with open(credentials_file_path) as conf_file:
    config = json.load(conf_file)
    # 1) build and sign JWT
    signed_jwt = build_jwt(config)
    # 2) get access token
    r = requests.post(token_url, data= {
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "assertion": signed_jwt.decode("utf-8")
    })
    token = r.json()
    print(f'token will expire in {token["expires_in"]} seconds')
    at = token["access_token"]
    # 3) call translate API
    r = requests.post(
        "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f'Bearer {at}'
        },
        json= {
            "q": "The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in the Giza pyramid complex.",
            "source": "en",
            "target": "es",
            "format": "text"
        })
    print(r.json())
```

Note that in the addendum, it's mentionned that some Google API doesn't need Access token and can work just by using the JWT in the `Authorization` header but it doesn't work for this translation API

Also, I guess you would want to use google client library to do the steps above depending on what language you use

> How can the static key be used in the the curl call in place of the
>   Authorization: Bearer?

You need to generate an API key in Google console (and have translation API enabled). Then you can use directly :

```
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Hello%20world&target=es&alt=json&source=en
```

Note that using `www.googleapis.com` also works :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Hello%20world&target=es&alt=json&source=en
```

Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```python
import requests

api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
text = "The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in the Giza pyramid complex"

r = requests.get(
    "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
    params = {
        "key": api_key,
        "q": text,
        "target": "es",
        "alt":"json",
        "source":"en"
    }
)
print(r.json())
```

Note that you could also use `POST` instead of `GET` like in the documentation but passing `key` as a query parameter :

```python
r = requests.post(
    "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
    params = {
        "key": api_key
    },
    json = {
        "q": text,
        "target": "es",
        "alt":"json",
        "source":"en"
    }
)
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a fix key that isn't dynamically generated from gcloud auth application-default print-access-token and without the need to setup the environmental variable?

You can use google translate api more simply by using api-key.

step by step...

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=your-project-id

[image]

The code example using the generated api-key is as follows.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?API-KEY');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$text1="The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in the Giza pyramid complex.";
$text2="this is second text example";
$post = array(
    'q'=> json_encode(array($text1,$text2)),
    'source'=>"en",
    'target'=> "sr",//serbian sr
    'format'=>"text",   
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$result=json_decode($response,true);
print_r($result['data']['translations']);
```