# Web scraping with Google Translate not working

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I have trouble understanding why in the below code the first URL returns the page, but the second does not.

```
    Sub Test()
    Dim URL, TRanslatedText As String
    Dim HTTPObject As Object

    ' first URL (works)        
    URL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=auto&sl=auto&tl=en&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=No entiendo"

    ' second URL (does not work)        
    'URL = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=No%20entiendo"

    Set HTTPObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    HTTPObject.Open "GET", URL, False
    HTTPObject.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    HTTPObject.send

    Cells(1, 1) = HTTPObject.responseText
    End Sub
```

Why does the second URL not work...?

Comment: It might be missing a request header

Comment: Isn’t the request header in the line with “HTTPObject.setRequestHeader”?

Comment: That only sets the "Content-type" request header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". There's loads more you can attach to a request and there's a bunch of defaults that are set when you create the request object. Maybe one of those is different.

Comment: At first I thought it was the `#` in the URL but I think that's fine...

Comment: Both URLs work when I cut-and-paste them to a browser.

Comment: It is the # in the URL. That's purely client-side, it's not sent with the request (`https://translate.google.com/#view=home...` is exactly the same request as `https://translate.google.com/`).

Comment: Yeah I just spotted that on the network traffic. With the `#` in there, it only triggers `https://translate.google.com/` and the browser does the rest, so including everything from # in a direct GET request confuses google. Confuses me also.

Comment: Thanks jamheadart and Guy Incognito for pointing out the likely culprit to be the client-side browser. Would you be able to give me a pointer as to how _a priori_ get the right URL if I want to extract the _entire_ content of a website that it shows me on the browser? How to go about this? Any literature you might recommend?

Comment: @PakMariman if you want to get google translate output, it may not be necessary to scrape the website for it since there is an API, checkout the API Key part of the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62222205/2614364)