# How can I a Google Api restful endpoint using service key?

Tags: rest, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, restful-authentication

I'm using postman to memic a restful api call and trying to access google sheets API end point. When I try to access my endpoint it returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

which is fair enough as I did not use my API key. I created a service account and got a json file, but I plan to access using a rest endpoint so need to pass token in header but I'm not sure how.

I looked at the json file and wasn't sure what to extract in order to pass it for my rest call.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling Google Services from Postman, you would need to re-create the flow for getting an access token form service account credentials :

- build and encode the JWT payload from the data from credentials files (to populate aud, iss, sub, iat and exp)
- request an access token using that JWT
- make the request to the API using this access token

You can find a complete guide for this flow is located here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Here is an example in python. You will need to install pycrypto and pyjwt to run this script :

```python
import requests
import json
import jwt
import time

#for RS256 you may need this
#from jwt.contrib.algorithms.pycrypto import RSAAlgorithm
#jwt.register_algorithm('RS256', RSAAlgorithm(RSAAlgorithm.SHA256))

token_url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
credentials_file_path = "./google.json"

#build and sign JWT
def build_jwt(config):
    iat = int(time.time())
    exp = iat + 3600
    payload = {
        'iss': config["client_email"],
        'sub': config["client_email"],
        'aud': token_url,
        'iat': iat,
        'exp': exp,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    }
    jwt_headers = {
        'kid': config["private_key_id"],
        "alg": 'RS256',
        "typ": 'JWT'
    }
    signed_jwt = jwt.encode(
        payload, 
        config["private_key"], 
        headers = jwt_headers,
        algorithm = 'RS256'
    )
    return signed_jwt

with open(credentials_file_path) as conf_file:
    config = json.load(conf_file)
    # 1) build and sign JWT
    signed_jwt = build_jwt(config)
    # 2) get access token
    r = requests.post(token_url, data= {
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "assertion": signed_jwt.decode("utf-8")
    })
    token = r.json()
    print(f'token will expire in {token["expires_in"]} seconds')
    at = token["access_token"]
    print(at)
```

Note the value of the scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

Probably, you can do all the above flow using Google API library depending on what 
 programming language you prefer

The script above will print the access token :

```
ya29.AHES67zeEn-RDg9CA5gGKMLKuG4uVB7W4O4WjNr-NBfY6Dtad4vbIZ
```

Then you can use it in Postman in `Authorization` header as `Bearer {TOKEN}`.

Or using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) :

```bash
curl "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$SPREADSHEET_ID" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Note: you can find an example of using service account keys to call Google translate API [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62222205/2614364)